# Radiobutton in List-item blocking OnClick event?

Tags: android, list, onclick, radio-button

I'm trying to have a simple list with 2 TextView's and 1 RadioButton per item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/list_item_selector" android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView android:text="sd" android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingTop="10dip" android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

    <TextView android:text="sd" android:id="@+id/distance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/grey" android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<RadioButton android:id="@+id/radioButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:checked="false"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The relevant associated Java-code is

```
            ListView lv = getListView();
            lv.setAdapter(new FilialSelArrayAdapter(getActivity()));

            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "item clicked");
                }
            });
```

This code already worked fine. However, after adding a RadioButton to the list items, the onclick handler stopped working, it isn't invoked anymore. Why?

Answer (score 0):

You have put your RadioButton out of LinearLayout. Please check....

Comment: there's an outer RelativeLayout. When pasting the code in here it got lost bcs of tab spacing. I wasn't aware of that, sorry.

Comment: I debugged your code and the RadioButton is consuming your setOnItemClickListener......you can make your textview clickable inside your adapter and it will work fine......

Comment: but why does it consume the click if it's done outside of the RadioButton's views bounds?